# Pandas: Generate a histogram/pivot against timeseries data

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe, the first 5 rows of which are :

```
indexed.head(5)
>>>>
                              SOURCE_SYSTEM              TRADE_ID
endtime
2013-09-12 15:04:44                 SystemA       PXXX86883150911
2013-09-12 17:25:07                 SystemB       PXXX66048140211
2013-09-12 17:25:07                 SystemY       PYYY66049140211
2013-09-12 17:25:08                 SystemZ       PZZZ34553220311
2013-09-12 17:25:09                 SystemZ       PAAA76226310311
```

nb, the index is by a datetime column.

I want to generate 2 things:
i) a count of results by month (or some other length of time)
ii) a count of results split by period and a second column value (i.e. a pivot?)

I've been able to achieve the 1st by first creating a Period object:

```
prng = pd.period_range(indexed.index.min(), indexed.index.max(),freq='M')
```

And then iterating through that, performing a kind of lookup along the way:

```
for r in prng:
    print ( str(r), len(indexed[str(r)]) )
```

Which returns:

```
2013-09 8
2013-10 2
2013-11 4
2013-12 1069
2014-01 2242
2014-02 1338
2014-03 2567
2014-04 762
2014-05 1028
2014-06 1885
2014-07 4303
2014-08 879
2014-09 399
2014-10 6002
2014-11 622
2014-12 625
```

Which is sort of what I want for i) 
The question is, is there a simpler way of doing this? And how about my part ii) Perhaps there's a method using groupby and/or pivot? I've read the docs on these, but I'm missing the point somehow. Any suggestions please?

Comment: Can you explain how (ii) should work in a bit more detail?

Comment: Hi Ffisegydd, (ii) would be a list of months down the side, and then the contents of my SOURCE_SYSTEM column {'SystemA','SystemB','SystemC...,'SystemZ'} listed across the top, with coincidental cells containing a count of values. I think much like you've detailed in your answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do (i) much more easily using [`df.resample`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/timeseries.html#time-series-date-functionality) as shown below

```
import pandas as pd
from random import choice

N = 1024

dt = pd.date_range('1/1/2011', periods=N, freq='3H')
A = [choice('ABCD') for _ in range(N)]
B = [choice('WXYZ') for _ in range(N)]

df = pd.DataFrame(data={'A':A, 'B':B}, index=dt)
#                      A  B
# 2011-01-01 00:00:00  B  Z
# 2011-01-01 03:00:00  A  X
# 2011-01-01 06:00:00  B  Y
# 2011-01-01 09:00:00  D  W
# 2011-01-01 12:00:00  A  Z
# ...    

resampled = df.resample('M', how='count')
#              A    B
#2011-01-31  248  248
#2011-02-28  224  224
#2011-03-31  248  248
#2011-04-30  240  240
#2011-05-31   64   64
```

And for (ii) you can use [`pd.pivot_table`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reshaping.html#pivot-tables-and-cross-tabulations), once you've created a `month` column which holds the year-month for you to pivot with.

```
df['month'] = ['{}-{}'.format(y, m) for y, m in zip(df.index.year, df.index.month)]

pivot = pd.pivot_table(df, values='B', index='month', columns='A', aggfunc='count')
#A        A   B   C   D
#month
#2011-1  64  58  67  59
#2011-2  62  52  47  63
#2011-3  70  58  59  61
#2011-4  52  63  64  61
#2011-5  16  19  15  14
```

Comment: I've tried the following:     `test = pd.pivot_table(indexed, index='month', values='SOURCE_SYSTEM_ID', columns='SOURCE_SYSTEM_ID', aggfunc='count')`    but get a     `TypeError: pivot_table() got an unexpected keyword argument 'index'`    error.

Comment: `pd.__version__` returns `'0.11.0'` aha - ok, will give that a try - that might explain how some of this has been proving tricky vs the docs.

Comment: Excellent - I tried a mixture of the above and took a look at the 0.11 docs - and came up with this line `q = pd.pivot_table(indexed, rows='month', values='TRADE_ID', cols='SOURCE_SYSTEM_ID',aggfunc='count')` which has generated what I'm looking for - result!

Comment: @TomKimber: I hope your comment doesn't mean you're using version 0.11-- even if you don't care about the new features, so many bugs have been fixed since then that using that version feels pretty dangerous. :-)

Comment: @DSM unfortunately yes - I'm behind a corporate firewall, so keeping up-to-date is proving tricky. I have just managed to sneak an Anaconda install in though, so should be moving to 0.14 shortly... :) 
I was hoping for 0.15 as the `.eval` functions look fairly handy for what I'm doing.